# Telegram bot stops after a few hours on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, telegram, pythonanywhere

I've got a simple Telegram bot, I don't think the code matters but I used telebot library.

I uploaded it to pythonanywhere, installed virtual environment and all libraries that needed.

Whenever I type python.script.py in the bash console, script works for, say, 5 hours, then it stops. How do I make it run forever?

Comment: Where do you run it? On you local PC? Then may be it was just in stand by mode. Is it on remote Linux server? Tell us what you find in syslog what is related to your process?

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere does not keep consoles running forever. They need to be stopped on occasion to manage the service. See the PythonAnywhere documentation for details about keeping tasks running.